# Convert all the BGR value within a specific range to white(255,255,255)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have input png image of which I want to convert all the pixels belonging to specific range starting (2,2,2) ending (255,255,255) to white(255,255,255)

```
im = cv2.imread('3.png')  # I am reading the image

lower_range = np.array([2,2,2]). # I specific the lower range
upper_range = np.array([255,255,255]) # I specify the upper range

im[np.where((im == [0,0,255]).all(axis = 2))] = [255,255,255]  # converts all red pixels to white
cv2.imwrite('out.png', im)
```

My question is how can I modify  `im[np.where((im == [0,0,255]).all(axis = 2))] = [255,255,255]`. Such that it covers range of colours mentioned in line 2 and 3 and converts them all to white.

Answer (score 1):

There's [cv2.inRange](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#cv2.inRange) which yields a mask which can be used to change color as you wish.

```
mask1 = cv2.inRange(im, lower_range, upper_range)
im[np.where(mask)] = [255,255,255]
```

On a side note, your range of colors is pretty big (almost covers everything).

Comment: "your range of colors is pretty big (almost covers everything)" Yes this is for a specific purpose, I am doing a segmentation task where the background is (0,0,0) and the object to be segmented is (1,1,1) all the other pixels are needed to be white

Comment: If that's the case, then it's better just copying the (0,0,0)'s and (1,1,1)'s to a white image of the same size.

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe that is a better idea, I just tried your code it is not working for this Image https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajinkya933/Extracting-text-from-images-using-Google-Vision/master/3.png.  Please note the linked image may look completely black but if you download it, it has very faint white outline which I don't want

Comment: It works with that image, the whites become whiter. However, the image contains colors like [224,   0,   0], which is not covered by the given range. I think you'd better do the copying.

Comment: Quick question:   Ive created whiteFrame = 255 * np.ones((600,450,3), np.uint8) \

lower_range = np.array([0,0,0])  \
upper_range = np.array([1,1,1])  \
mask = cv2.inRange(im, lower_range, upper_range). \ how should I overlap images using this code ?

Comment: that don't work if you have (1,0,1). Just copy the zero's and one's separately: `mask0 = im == (0,0,0); whiteFrame = cv2.bitwise_and(img, whiteFrame, mask=mask0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191772/discussion-between-abc-and-quang-hoang).